# Cleaner way to replace values in a tibble list

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, tibble

I’m trying to come up with a cleaner way (less typing) to replace values in lists in a large tibble. From looking around online, it seems common to use subsetting rather than $ to replace values, like this:

```
mtcars["cyl"][mtcars["cyl"] == 4] <- 6
```

I would like to do this with less code because I need to do it manually (with different replacements) 2-3 times for over 200 columns in this tibble. My tibble name and column names are also pretty long, making this cumbersome.

I tried to write my own function that did the same thing, but I couldn’t get it to work:

```
val_set <- function(df, column, old_value, replace) {
  df[column][df[column] == old_value] <- replace
}
```

Then I learned about the replace function, but I can only make it work with $ and not []. And when I go to check on the change with View(), the values remain unchanged. Does that have to do with using $ vs []?

```
replace(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$cyl == 4, 6)
```

What is the safest and fastest way to do this?

Comment: In data.table it can be done like this:  `library(data.table); mtcarsDT <- data.table(mtcars); mtcarsDT[cyl == 4, cyl := 6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just that we need to assign it back to the object

```
val_set <- function(df, column, old_value, replace) {
  df[[column]][df[[column]] == old_value] <- replace
  df
}
mtcars <- val_set(mtcars, 'cyl', 4, 6)
```

Now, check the 'mtcars' 'cyl' column

```
mtcars$cyl
 [1] 6 6 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 6 6 6 8 6 8 6
```

Comment: with a little tweak, we can pass the column name as a variable instead of a character string. But this is already very close to what OP needs.

Comment: Thank you both for this answer! If you don't mind, @M--,  could you describe what that tweak would be for my own knowledge?

Comment: @ajt10 Just add this line at the beginning of the function: ```column <- deparse(substitute(column))``` and then you can run it like this: ```mtcars <- val_set(mtcars, cyl, 4, 6)```.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `within` and avoid making your own custom function. That makes the code cleaner and more legible.

```
within(mtcars, cyl[cyl == 4] <- 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the second part of your question on using `replace` I think you should treat column names as characters. Change your code to this:

```
replace(mtcars["cyl"], mtcars["cyl"] == 4, 6)
```